# Running a .exe of GUI based application in background

Tags: python, windows, user-interface, service, cmd

I have developed a GUI based application having both front-end(using Tkinter) and back-end in python. Later, I used py2exe to convert this application to .exe file. When I run this .exe file two separate windows open up, one of the application GUI and second of the command prompt.

At the end I would like to develop the software in which you click on the .exe and GUI pops up and you can use the software. No command prompt window should be opened. This is my first GUI based application and pardon me if my question sounds naive.

Comment: so where is the problem??

Comment: When I run the .exe file, the command prompt window also pops up. I dont want that window to open up. Just the application GUI should open up. @SSH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the following in your setup.py:

```
setup(
    ...
    windows=['name_of_your_file.py']
    ...
)
```

This indicates to py2exe that you want a GUI without a console window for output.